# Parse emails in outlook format

Tags: javascript, regex, outlook

I'm trying to parse the following string, so that I can get the emails in between `<` and `>` characters in an array.

```
Some Name <emai1@email.com>; Some Name2 <emai2@email.com>; Some Name 3 <emai3@email.com>; Some Name 4 <emai4@email.com>;
```

I have looked around and tried many regex I found online to solve similar problems like this one:

```
const result = str.match(/(?<=<)\w+(?=>)/g) || [];
```

However none of them work and now I'm just blindfolded hitting my head against a brick wall.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match the `<` and the `>` and might use a capture group with a negated character class:

```
<([^\s<>@]+@[^\s<>@]+)>
```

- `<` Match opening `<`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\s<>@]+` Match any char except a whitespace char `<` `>` `@`
  - `@[^\s<>@]+` Match `@` and again the previous pattern
- `)` Close group 1
- `>` Match closing `>`

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x4FWiV/1)

Or if there has to be a dot at the end:

```
<([^\s<>@]+@[^\s<>@]+\.[^\s<>@]+)>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2TB9Hp/1)

```js
const s = "Some Name <emai1@email.com>; Some Name2 <emai2@email.com>; Some Name 3 <emai3@email.com>; Some Name 4 <emai4@email.com>;";
const regex = /<([^\s<>@]+@[^\s<>@]+)>/g;
let result = Array.from(s.matchAll(regex), m => m[1])
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi that's neat, works like a charm! Still mystified with the world of regex but your explanation was really good, thanks again!